# Which is the most efficient way of creating "pen tool" for drawing, like in the Paint?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a "pen", but now when i start drawing the CPU is load over 60%, and it's getting lag. Is this just a very bad algorithm for this task?
Found it on the msdn and change a bit.
Everytime when mouse moves over the canvas im creating a line from previous mouse position to current.

There it is(I'm really newbie)

```
private void MainCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Canvas.SetTop(el, customCursor.Y - cursorRadius / 2);
        Canvas.SetLeft(el, customCursor.X - cursorRadius / 2);

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            myPath = new Path();
            mainCanvas.Children.Add(myPath);
            geometry = new StreamGeometry();
            myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            myPath.StrokeThickness = 5;
            geometry.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;
            using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geometry.Open())
            {
                ctx.BeginFigure(customCursor, false /* is filled */, false /* is closed */);

                ctx.LineTo(e.GetPosition(mainCanvas), true /* is stroked */, false /* is smooth join */);

            }

            geometry.Freeze();

            myPath.Data = geometry;
            customCursor = e.GetPosition(mainCanvas);

        }
    }
```

I read about Drawing and Shape classes, but now i'm totally confused, what should i use and what way.

Comment: Also i'd to implement such functionality as zoom, selecting, and transforming(only size and rotation).

Comment: Adding Path elements with a StreamGeometry with only a single line segment could be drastically simplified by adding single Line elements instead. However, that would still be extremely inefficient. Better add Points to a *single* Polyline child element of the Canvas. Even better, use an InkCanvas.

Comment: is it possible to use absolute positioning with inkcanvas, if i want to add and image, or move particular objects? And creating some kind of a layers system?

Comment: No idea. Give it a try. Or try the Polyline approach first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game I've been working on includes a map editor.  It's a battle simulation set in c18-19th so EG Waterloo, Custer's last stand, Isandlwana.

Amongst other functionality, the user can draw area or line shaped terrains.  EG Woods or roads.

This is a fairly complicated process so this is necessarily an overview.

I use an InkCanvas for drawing curves because ink is very good at smoothing out the little jiggles as you draw. And of course that has a pen cursor.

I then translate the user's stroke they drew.  I work out all the points in it, build a geometry.

This is templated out into UI using datatemplates. I have a Canvas as the itemspanel of an itemscontrol hosts all these.

There are also buildings and places which you just click somewhere to place. There are multiple templates for buildings.

Each thing drawn or added is a viewmodel which goes in an observablecollection bound to the itemssource of that itemscontrol.  You can bind panel.zindex but by default the order they are added defines zindex.

There isn't explicitly a layering system you can group these by but you could fairly easily introduce a virtual one by adding a layer property to your viewmodel.

I also bind a filtered version of this to a listbox so the user can manipulate attributes of each terrain. Your version could include things like a transform to make things bigger.

I haven't implemented any dragging of these but I have a similar set up for units in the scenario editor. You can drag units around to position them.  They have X and Y properties I bind to the itemtemplate's canvas.left and canvas.top. The user can rotate units using the mousewheel. I have a bound command does that.